# Is there a WYSIWYG Text and HTML Editor which support block of code?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

In Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, I can use #region...#endregion to Outline and Hide Code.

Is there a WYSIWYG Text and HTML Editor which support #region...#endregion function?

BTW, http://ckeditor.com/ don't support it.

And more, how can I create a editor with c# to do it?

Comment: All text editors are WYSIWYG. No HTML editor is WYSIWYG.

Comment: @Jay: incorrect. There are many JavaScript based HTML editor having WYSIWYG feature, like TinyMCE (http://www.tinymce.com/).

Comment: @Shivan Clarification - no editor in which you are folding regions of HTML is WYSIWYG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you mean standalone or within VS, if VS, then you could build one on top of [DXCore](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/).

> Extend Visual Studio® Right Now
>
> Both CodeRush for Visual Studio® and Refactor! for Visual Studio® were
>   designed upon a common IDE (Integrated Development Environment)
>   integration framework called DXCore for Visual Studio® .NET.
>
> In the interest of encouraging developers to be pro-active about
>   productivity, Developer Express is making available for general
>   download DXCore for Visual Studio® so that developers can build their
>   own productivity plug-ins to extend the Visual Studio® IDE themselves
>   using a simple visual framework for IDE extension.

Comment: Thanks! I hope to do a standalone which can work within asp.net webpage